# Why it actually calls FindByEmailAsync() when the code calls FindByEmail()

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am working with one legacy .NET MVC project left by my colleague, he uses Microsoft Identity System to deal with user authentication. In the LoginController:

```
var user = userManager.FindByEmail(modelUserName);
if(user == null)
{
  // the user was not found..
}
else
{}
```

Later I realized that FindByEmail() is actually a precompiled function written by Microsoft in the UserManagerExtension class. However, my colleague also defines another similar function called FindByEmailAsync() in his customized UserManager class:

```
public Task<User> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
{
  return ..
}
```

and when I debug the project, I found the code in LoginController somehow called FindByEmailAsync() when it run "var user = userManager.FindByEmail(modelUserName)", why is that?

Comment: are you sure about the definition of `FindByEmailAsync`? does it no have `override` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `FindByEmail` is an extension method. Only this is a thin wrapper  that just calls `FindByEmailAsync` in a sync manner - easy to inspect the original [source code](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Extensions/UserManagerExtensions.cs) - search for "FindByEmail" on the page.

So there is no surprise you see async method called when you actually call sync version in your code.